# Why are images not showing in IE in html email?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, email

Hi I created an html email and tested it by sending it to different email clients like Gmail, Yahoo Webmail, and Windows Live Hotmail.

For images I used

```
<img src="http://www.mysite.com/image.png"/>
```

The image shows up in Gmail and Yahoo Webmail after unblocking it, but in Hotmail, even after the image is unblocked the image still does not show up.

I tested this in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari and Internet Explorer. This only occurs in Internet Exlplorer.

Why is this not working in Hotmail in IE?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of a PNG file is it? Have you tested it with other images?

Comment: Have you tried using IE9's console to inspect it? You are talking about Hotmail in a browser window, right?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem.  Some web pages would not show and clicking on the picture on properties reported the picture as a Blank.Gif.  I went into  Manage-Add-ons in IE 9 & 10 and went to Tracking Protection and disabled all protection, closed IE and restarted.  Problem went away and pictures were visible.  Went back into Manage add-ons and into Tracking Protection and re-read all listings and re-enabled one at a time looking for the problem listing.  I now use a personal listing based on what I want blocked.  Hope this helps someone, I have been trying to find a solution to this for the past 6 months.

Answer (score 0):

if you're in IE9, try this:
click tools
click internet options
click security tab
click trusted Sites green check mark, 
click sites on right-hand side, 
add to the zone:https://login.live.com
click add
click close
click ok